# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(e^x-1)( \ln(1+\sin3x)}{\ln(1-\sin x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find the limit of $\dfrac{(e^x-1)(\ln(1+\sin3x))}{\ln(1-\sin x)}$, I know there is equivalences for ($e^x-1) \approx x$ and $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ but I don't know how to change the bottom one. Any hints?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

A necessary skill and prerequisite to solve limit is the knowledge of the standard limits; in this case we are referring to (as $x \to 0$)

- $\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$
- $\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$
- $\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$

using these results we have that

$$\frac{(e^x-1)(\ln(1+\sin(3x)))}{\ln(1-\sin x)}= $$$$=\frac{e^x-1}x\cdot\frac{\ln(1+\sin(3x))}{\sin (3x)} \cdot\frac{-\sin x}{\ln(1-\sin x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\cdot\frac{x}{-\sin x}\cdot 3x \to$$ $$\to1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot (-1) \cdot 0=0$$

As an alternative, we can use the first order approximation obtained directly by the standard limits and notably

- $e^x-1=x+o(x)$
- $\sin x= x+o(x)$
- $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$

to obtain

$$\frac{(e^x-1)(\ln(1+\sin(3x)))}{\ln(1-\sin x)}=\frac{(x+o(x))(\ln(1+3x+o(x))}{\ln(1-x+o(x))}=$$

$$=\frac{(x+o(x))(3x+o(x))}{(-x+o(x))}=\frac{3x^2+o(x^2)}{-x+o(x)}=\frac{3x+o(x)}{-1+o(1)} \to 0$$

As indicated also in other answers, we can also proceed by "asymptotic equivalents" directly obtained by the same satndard limits and notably

- $e^x-1\sim x$
- $\sin x\sim x$
- $\log(1+x)\sim x$

to obtain

$$\frac{(e^x-1)(\ln(1+\sin(3x)))}{\ln(1-\sin x)}\sim \frac{x\cdot \ln(1+3x)}{\ln(1-x)}\sim \frac{x\cdot 3x}{-x}=-3x \to 0$$

which is a faster method but we need to proceed carefully with that since it can lead to great mistakes as for example for $\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$ using asymptotic equivalents we obtain

$$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\sim \frac{x-x}{x^3}=0$$

which is wrong.

To see why it is wrong it suffices to use first order approximation to obtain

$$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\frac{x-x+o(x)}{x^3}=\frac{o(1)}{x^2}$$

which is an indeterminate form and therefore we can't conclude.

To solve it we need others method, notably L'Hospital, Taylor's, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest is using *asymptotic equivalents*:

we know that $\;\sin u, \:\ln(1+u)\sim_0 u$ and, as $\mathrm e^x-1=1+x+o(x)-1$ $=x+o(x)$,  we have $\:\mathrm e^x-1\sim_0 x$. We obtain
$$\frac{(e^x-1)( \ln(1+\sin3x)}{\ln(1-\sin x)}\sim_0\frac{x\cdot 3x}{-x}=-3x\to 0 \quad\text{ as }x\to 0$$

Comment: Always to use with caution! :)

Comment: Yes, but I guess people who know a bit  asymptotic calculus know the rules of use  for equivalents… (a risky bet?)

Comment: Yes if we use that taking into account implicitely the little-o or big-O part then it is a fine method otherwise we know it can lead to big mistakes.

Comment: I've already that some use $\approx$ instead (which is not really a mathematical notion).

Comment: B.t.w. ilittle-o *is* implictely in the definition of equivamece, since $f\sim g\iff f=g+o(g)$.

Comment: Yes that's fine, what I mean is that not expert users can easily lost these implicit assumption and use asymptotic equivalents not properly.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind both of your approximations come from the Taylor series expansions of these. For $x$ small, e.g. "near $0$," informally, you can ignore any terms with $x^2$ or higher degrees under the informal rationale that "$x$ is already small and less than $1$, so $x^n$ for $n>1$ is negligibly small. "

In total, you'll want to reference these series:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \;\;\;\;\; \ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \;\;\;\;\; \sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Correspondingly, for $x$ small,

$$e^x \approx 1+x \;\;\;\;\; \ln(1-x) \approx -x \;\;\;\;\; \sin(x) \approx x$$

The middle of course gives you $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ equivalently. (You sometimes see slightly different but equivalent series for the natural logarithm, I just used the one that came to mind for me.)

I'll also note that Taylor series aren't the only way to derive these approximations - indeed, it's overkill, since you only need the first derivative, but I feel it's easiest to remember via Taylor series. In any event, to approximate $f$ linearly about the point $x=a$, the general formula is $f(x) \approx f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)$. Take $a=0$ and $f$ to be any of those functions above, and you can derive the approximation that way.

---

Anyhow, try those substitutions. In particular, for the denominator, apply the sine one, and then apply the natural logarithm one.

However, note that this isn't the most rigorous  way to approach the limits. There's a sort of rigor underlying the use and substitution of these approximations, which I'm skipping over since you seem to be okay with these. To me this suggests that this is okay for your coursework as is.

Comment: The first order approximation or expansion don’t require Taylor’s series concept but just (first) derivative.

Comment: I totally agree with your advice to be careful with this approach.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the Taylor series thing. I just find that easier to remember and make it my go-to for some reason. Anyhow, I added a note on the concept of linear approximation.

Comment: I’m also going to add something to clarify that concept and for the different ways to solve this kind of limits.